# why title_activity_main is needed in strings file

Tags: android

I am trying to ask one basic question in Android. I am trying to write my first app in Android and I'm confused what purpose following line serves :

```
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
```

If I do not add it, my build shows error.

Comment: you can refer to the string in your layout's with `@string/title_activity_main` or in activity `getString(R.string.title_activity_main).`

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because, the value of `title_activity_main` is being used somewhere in your application.

Case 1 : Inside the java code in the way @Raghunandan mentioned in the comments e.g. `getString(R.string.title_activity_main);`

Case 2 : Inside your android manifest `android:label="@string/title_activity_main"` or an xml layout e.g `android:text="@string/title_activity_main"`

If you remove the line from your strings.xml file, your IDE will most likely show you the file where the string was being used by showing an error in that file and you'll be able to find the exact place.

Answer (score 0):

That's the name of your main activity, which is displayed in the `Action Bar`. Every activity has one.

[image: The action bar]

[Here, in the image, the Activity Name is shown as *Action Bar*]

Your application refers to it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the root directory of your project.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.someApp"
        **android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >**
    </activity>
</application>
```

And when you remove the string from the `strings.xml` file, the compiler cannot find the string resource needed and thus shows an error. Meanwhile, feel free to change the string and play with it.